# Four-parameter cumulative Weibull fit

Tags: python, scipy, weibull

I'm trying to find the best fit to a four-parameter cumulative Weibull fit of the type:

f(x) = A*(1-exp(-((x-xo)/W)^s)

using curve_fit in scipy.optimize as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def weib(x, *p):
    XSsat, Lo, W, s = p
    return XSsat*(1-np.exp(-((x-Lo)/W)**s))

x_data = [10.1, 11.7, 14.3, 20.2, 32.1, 37.1, 45.5, 64.2]
y_data = [2.96e-6, 2.58e-5, 1.72e-4, 1.18e-3, 2.27e-2, 3.26e-2, 3.98e-2,   4.67e-2]
p0 = [5e-2, 0, 35, 3]
coeff, pcov = curve_fit(weib, x_data, y_data, p0=p0)
```

However, what I get as an output is:

```
print coeff
[ nan  nan  nan  nan]
```

The problem seems to be related to the fact that the function is not defined for x

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I was meant to say that "The problem seems to be related to the fact that the function is not defined for x < Lo, as the fit works perfectly when only the remaining thee parameters are used".

Comment: Yields good values here with numpy 1.9.0 and scipy 0.14.0: pcoeff = [0.04575166  10.09999817  25.57229605   2.77544717]

Comment: Indeed, I updated to scipy 0.15.1 and it works. Thanks a lot for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to implement your own method to fit the parameters you could use an existing library. [SurPyval](https://surpyval.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#) allows you to do exactly what you want with relative ease (I am it's developer).

```py
import surpyval as surv

x = [10.1, 11.7, 14.3, 20.2, 32.1, 37.1, 45.5, 64.2]
model = surv.ExpoWeibull.fit(x, offset=True, how="MPS")
model
```

```
Parametric SurPyval Model
=========================
Distribution        : ExpoWeibull
Fitted by           : MPS
Offset (gamma)      : 9.689564921508342
Parameters          :
     alpha: 67.02718103263011
      beta: 3.704898338328615
        mu: 0.11727921731925008
```

The parameters of the Exponentiated Weibull can be seen [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiated_Weibull_distribution). The output can be mapped to the parameterisation in wikipedia such that k is beta, lambda is alpha, and mu is alpha. The "gamma" parameter is just a transform of x -> x - gamma.

"offset" tells it to add the "gamma" parameters.

Also, the "MPS" is the [Maximum Product of Spacing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_spacing_estimation) method which is very robust when using offset distributions. Using Maximum Likelihood "MLE" actually fails.